# Error en la codificación al scrapear sitio web

Tags: javascript, nodejs, typescript, promesas, scrapy

estoy obteniendo datos de un sitio web y me trae carácteres extraños.
Según su código está codificado en ISO-8859-1.
Pero cuando paso la página por https://validator.w3.org me dice que su codificación es [windows-1252](/questions/tagged/windows-1252) realmente.

Estoy trabajando con request y iconv-lite.

```js
getDataRequest(url).then((res: any) => {
const str = iconv.decode(res, 'windows1252');
        const $ = cheerio.load(str);
        console.log($);
 }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
});
```

```js
let getDataRequest = async (url: any) => {
    const KEY = 'b8eb3f617b775dec109d7b82076eec34';
    const URL = `http://api.scraperapi.com/?api_key=${KEY}&url=${url}`;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request({ uri: URL, encoding: null, method: 'GET' }, function (error: any, response: any, body: any) {
            if (error) {
                return reject(error);
            } else {
                console.log(body);
                return resolve(body);                
            }
        });
    });
}
```

No consigo obtener las palabras con tildes bien.

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Revisa esta respuesta, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31834790/node-js-how-to-http-get-and-decode-encode-response-in-custom-format.

Comment: `function retrieve(url, callback) {
  http.get(url, function(res) {
    res.pipe(iconv.decodeStream('win1252')).collect(callback);
  });
}`